# Next.js v14 - Fetch JSON API

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a small problem. I can't put my Json API on my TypeScript page with Next.js

My code:

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import type { Metadata } from 'next';
import { Montserrat } from 'next/font/google';
import './../assets/css/globals.css';
import './../assets/libs/devicon/devicon.min.css';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Title',
  description: 'Example',
};

const montserrat_thin = Montserrat({ weight: ['100'], style: ['normal'], subsets: ['latin'] });
const montserrat_regular = Montserrat({ weight: ['400'], style: ['normal'], subsets: ['latin'] });
const montserrat_semiblack = Montserrat({ weight: ['700'], style: ['normal'], subsets: ['latin'] });
const montserrat_black = Montserrat({ weight: ['900'], style: ['normal'], subsets: ['latin'] });

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className={montserrat_regular.className}>
        <div className="flex gap-x-8 gap-y-8 skewY-0 mx-auto flex max-w-7xl">
            <div className="relative p-5">
                <span className={`${montserrat_thin.className} prenom`}>Test</span>
                <span className={`${montserrat_black.className} nom`}>Test</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="mateo-grid bg-mateo-unique h-[100%]">
            <div className="skewY-0 mx-auto max-w-7xl top-[-7rem] padding-right relative">
                <div className="w-full columns-1">
                    <h1 className={montserrat_black.className+ " titre"}>Test</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="w-full flex grid p-2 grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-4">

                { CODE HERE }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

API I want to use.

https://api.truckyapp.com/v2/events

I tried to do a fetch with Node.js however, I get the error:

```
3 | import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
           : ^^^^^^^^^
```

Second question. How do I /page/<slug_id> to see the contents of an "event" from this API?